# Fraction involving Surds

Tags: fractions

Fraction involving Surds. Can anyone please show me the working out?

$$
 \frac{(\sqrt{6}-1)}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{(\sqrt{6}+2)}{2\sqrt{3}}
$$

I did this and it was incorrect:

$$
  2\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{6}-1) + \frac{\sqrt{3}(\sqrt{6} + 2)}{\sqrt{3}\times 2\sqrt{3}}
$$

$$
 2\sqrt{18} - 2\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{18} + \frac{2\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3}\times 2\sqrt{3}} 
$$

Thanks!

Edit: This is my answer, which I now understand from my math teacher:

$$
 \frac{(\sqrt{6}-1)}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{(\sqrt{6}+2)}{2\sqrt{3}}
$$

$$
 \frac{2sqrt{3}(\sqrt{6}-1)}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{sqrt3(\sqrt{6}+2)}{2\sqrt{3}}
$$

$$

2\sqrt{18} - 2\sqrt{3} + sqrt{18} + 2\sqrt{3}\6

Comment: Apologies, I wrote the question incorrectly, it is actually: (√6-1)/√3 + (√6+2)/(2√3)

Comment: I've edited the text to show you how to write the equations in MathJax.  Please edit the expressions in the question using that as a guide.

Comment: Will my question not be answered unless I use MathJax?

Comment: I wouldn't say that, @Enzo , it's just this community's standard for writing mathematics. And now you have an example to learn from.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely try to learn MathJax in future questions

Comment: Thanks for the edit Biswajit

Comment: We want to bring the two expressions to a common denominator. Convenient is $2\sqrt{3}$. So the first term is $\frac{2(\sqrt{6}-1)}{2\sqrt{3}}$. Now we can add the tops freely. There will be a great deal of simplification.

Comment: @Enzo Actually, this site(http://functionspace.com/equationeditor) might prove helpful for Latex formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{(\sqrt{6}-1)}{\sqrt{3}} + \frac{(\sqrt{6}+2)}{2\sqrt{3}}
&=\frac{2(\sqrt{6}-1)}{2\sqrt{3}} + \frac{(\sqrt{6}+2)}{2\sqrt{3}}
\qquad\text{put the fractions over a common denominator}\\
&=\frac{2(\sqrt{6}-1)+(\sqrt{6}+2)}{2\sqrt{3}}
\qquad\text{add the numerators}\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{6}-2+\sqrt{6}+2}{2\sqrt{3}}
\qquad\text{use the distributive law to get rid of parentheses}\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt{6}}{2\sqrt{3}}
\qquad\text{simple algebra}\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt{2\cdot 3}}{2\sqrt{3}}
\qquad\text{setup to get rid of }\sqrt{3}\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt{2}\sqrt{ 3}}{2\sqrt{3}}
\qquad\text{use }\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}\\
&=\frac{3\sqrt{2}}{2}
\qquad\text{and its gone}\\
\end{array}
$

Comment: Thanks Marty! That is the correct answer, however I am pretty bad at mathematics so I don't actually understand how you got the answer. Could you please explain the equations or rules used to reach the answer?

Comment: I used \frac { a }{ b } -\frac { c }{ d } =\frac { ad-bc }{ bd }

Comment: I added a lot of comments to explain each step.

Comment: Thanks Marty, really appreciate the help!